# Detect zeros and convert them?

Tags: javascript

I want when user enter something like this :

```
"050"  = "50"
"00050" =  "50"
"000050" = "50"
"00000xxx" = "xxx"
"00,50"  =  "0,50"
"000,50" = "0,50" 
"00000,xx" = "0,xx"
```

Its type of string.
Any suggestion how can i achive this ? 
this.value = vai
I tried with replace but it replace all zeros then.

What i want to achive is every string if there is no comma and starts with zero to remove that zero ( it can be more than one zero).
Also for every string that start with zero and have come to take just last one so when i enter 0000000,40 to get 0,40.

Comment: what is the type?

Comment: Is the "and" part of your input, ie. should it be stripped, too, or is this a comment? Please put strings in quotation marks so we know what exactly you mean, e.g. what to do with spaces.

Comment: its a comment ...its type of string

Comment: is `000,50` -> `0.5` acceptable?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What about your corner cases? If "00,xx" → "0,xx",  then ",xx" should be normalized to "0,xx", shan't it? Is "x" a placeholder for digits or any character that is not a zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following regex to replace all zeros not followed by `,` and not at the end of the string: `0(?!,)(?!$)`

```js
var tests = [
  '050',
  '00050',
  '000050',
  '00000xxx',
  '00,50',
  '000,50',
  '00000,xx'
];

tests.forEach(function(test) {
  console.log(test, test.replace(/0(?!,)(?!$)/g, ''));
});
```

Comment: unfortunately georg removed its comment in sake of perfection probably.. I came up to ```/^0+(?=[^,])/``` which handles the cases provided by op, the full zero but not sure if it is efficient...